# Loop through named range list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I found a lot of examples but it's not working in my case and I don't know why.
Very basic code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim namCur As Name

For Each namCur In ActiveSheet.Names
MsgBox "Name: " & namCur.Name & ", Refers To: " & namCur.RefersTo
Next namCur
End Sub
```

And I have the same issue when I use `Worksheets("Assumptions").Names`

When I watch `ActiveSheet.Name`, this is correct I get "Assumptions", you can see on the picture below the list of named ranges. But I never get the MsgBox and the For loop goes directly to the end.
Edit: Very important, I need to loop only this sheet's named ranges, not the whole workbook
Any idea?

[image: Printscreen]

I use Excel 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution will only list Names that have a scope set to only the ActiveSheet.

Change this

```
For Each namCur In ActiveSheet.Names
```

To this

```
For Each namCur In ThisWorkBook.Names
```

to list all names in the Workbook. You can then check the RefersTo address to check if it applies to the ActiveSheet.

```
Sub Test()

Dim namCur As Name
Dim TargetSheetName As String

TargetSheetName = "Assumptions"

For Each namCur In ThisWorkbook.Names

    If Range(namCur.RefersTo).Parent.Name = TargetSheetName Then MsgBox "Name: " & namCur.Name & ", Refers To: " & namCur.RefersTo

Next namCur

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. But I only to perform an action on named ranges of a particular sheets, not all workbook. This is why I tried Worksheets("Assumptions").Names because I want to loop on all named ranges of this sheet

Comment: Are you trying to see if a specific cell is within a named range on the sheet? Just wondering as there may be a better way rather than looping through all the named ranges on the sheet.

Comment: No this is a bit more complicated, I need to update another sheet with value included in assumptions sheet, but only in certain named ranges and if not empty. Everything is working except the fact I don't manage to loop through all named ranges

Comment: I've edited my answer. This will now list all Names that are pointing at cells/ranges on the Assumptions tab, regardless of which tab is active at the time.