# VBA loop for named ranges that hide rows

Tags: excel, vba

Following advice from here, [Loop through named range list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984778/loop-through-named-range-list), I have tried to make the following code more efficient with a loop.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("in1.1").Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("in1.1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
    Range("in1.2").Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("in1.2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

However, I still get a runtime error of various flavors, and I don't really understand how VBA properties work.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim TargetSheetName As String
    TargetSheetName = "Input data"

    For Each nmdrange In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Range(nmdrange.RefersTo).Parent.Name = TargetSheetName Then
        'Loop over benefits
            Range(nmdrange).Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (Range(nmdrange).Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
        End If
    Next nmdrange

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim nmdrange As Name, rng As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each nmdrange In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Set rng = Range(nmdrange.RefersTo) '<< set a variable to simplify subsequent code
        'you can use Me to refer to the sheet where this code is running
        If rng.Parent.Name = Me.Name Then
            'Loop over benefits
            rng.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (rng.Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
        End If
    Next nmdrange

haveError:
    '## alert if error
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error" & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in my spreadsheet it suppresses the error message and does nothing.

Comment: See my edit - it would help your question to specify exactly what you mean by "runtime error of various flavors" - it's pretty difficult to guess what the problem might be from that...

Comment: This time it's `ErrorMethod 'Range'of object '_Worksheet' failed`, but sometimes it was a error code 1004.

Comment: Additional ideas or sources of errors: the scope of the named range; there's a second "worksheet_calculate" sub for a different sheet; I added the application.enableevents because it would crash otherwise.

Comment: Where are your named ranges relative to the sheets containing the Calculate event handlers?

Comment: In the same sheet as I couldn't make named range references to other worksheets work

Comment: Do you have any merged cells on the sheet?

Comment: No merged cells

Comment: Any error values in the top-left cell of the named ranges?  I'm out of ideas pretty much...

Comment: No error messages, but those cells are formulas. Is it possible to monitor only those cells as in `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: The `Change` event isn't triggered by changes in formula results, so you do need the `Calculate` event here.  The code i posted worked fine in my test sheet, but there may be something else in your workbook which is interfering.  I can't really offer much else without access to something which reproduces your specific problem.

Comment: Got it. Could I use a `Worksheet_Change` in the sheet where a user inputs and apply the changes in cells of a different worksheet?

Comment: If there are known cells on the input sheet which would affect which rows needed to be hidden/unhidden of the other sheet, then Yes you could use the `Change` event on the input sheet to trigger your checks.

Comment: I got some other version to work by using this code, perhaps applies here, too: `If nmdrange.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = Me.Name Then`

Comment: The code I posted worked for me. I can't say why it's not working for you, and I have no way of testing "fixes" which might change the behaviour in your specific workbook.